# Bicycle rear hub sounding weird

Tags: hub, adjustment, axle

My rear axle broke about 2 weeks ago, and I replaced it with a new one.
I also replaced the ball bearings with new ones when I did this.

The issue I am having is when I'm going with a higher speed the rear hub is making some sounds as if there would be some friction there.

When I mounted the axle I tightener the cones so that the axle wouldn't wobble.
If I loosen the cones a bit it starts to wobble a bit.

What do you suggest I do in order to get rid of the noise? Should I try to let the axle a bit more loose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://sheldonbrown.com/brandt/cone-adjustment.html). The QR skewer when done up increases the bearing pre-load. Correct bearing adjustment requires a slight wobble when the wheel is off the bike, which stops when the wheel is installed and the QR Skewer done up.

Its a bit of trial an error getting it right for the first few times..

It may also be incorrect bearing size - are you sure you used the correct bearings? - or the broken axle may have caused damaged the hub bearing faces - did you check those before assembly?.

Comment: Yes, they are the same size. I compared them with the old ones before placing them there. I replaced the cones too (one of them had an indent in it). The hub looked okay.

Comment: I adjusted the cones as mentioned in the link you gave me and it seems to work okay now. Thanks for the help :)